# Extracting data that meet a threshold in another matrix

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I'm having some trouble in Matlab, and this might be more of a methodology/logic question.

So I have three netCDF files that I am loading into three separate  matrices. Two of these matrices are values of a test run for two different experiments (all three files are gridded), and the other is the p-value of the data between the two experiments.

I want to create a new netCDF file that has the values of the difference between the two experiments if that particular grid has a pvalue <= 0.05.

I thought this would be fairly easy. Here is what I implemented:

```
%find the difference between experiments, averaged over the 3rd dimension
yr_diff = mean(mat_2012-mat_1980,3);
yr_diff(pvalue >= 0.05) = NaN;
final_grid = yr_diff;
```

And then I used a fairly straight forward netCDF exporting scheme. To my knowledge, the mat_2012 and mat_1980 matrices are organized in the same as the pvalue matrix.

This produces a sort of weird grid that doesn't really show anything. The first image below shows filled contours of the differences, with black contour lines where the areas are significant. The second plot shows filled contours of the netCDF file created with this logic, with the same significant contour lines.

[image: full difference]
[image: incorrect netCDF]

So my question: Is the logic incorrect, and should I take a new direction? Is this something related to my exporting scheme? Or is this something else completely?

Comment: You are doing something what these 3 commands will do: `a=rand(5,5);b=logical(randi(2,[5 5])-1);a(b)=NaN;`. It looks correct to me (as in it is doing what it should). I don't know if its correct in the context of your problem.

Comment: Okay, well then I think this must be a problem with my exporting scheme or my visulaisation software. I used matlabs native contouring and the values were correct. When I use the the files in a grid context, everything blows up. Thank you for help!

Comment: You can run those 3 commands and see if what you are doing is getting done. If your matrices are big, you may not have spotted the bug. Whenever you are debugging, it is better to work with smaller matrices first (if you don't understand where the problem is).

Comment: I figured out it wasn't so much my logic, but rather the exporting scheme..which should have been an easy fix. For anybody seeking this in the future -- while exporting netCDF's from matlab, make all of your variables are the INVERSE of the matrix, e.g., if you are using matrix A, export as A'